# How to call mat-options programatically from function?

Tags: angular, triggers, event-handling, mouselistener, eventtrigger

I need to implement handling for double click event on mat-select component. The idea is to be able to call a function on a double click event, but keeping the normal behavior on single click event. Usually this is not possible because mat-select displays mat-options immediately not allowing to detect a double click event.

If I try to add some delay with a setTimeOut for example when mat-select is triggered, the mat-options popup is displayed without any delay. I found a workaround so I can double click on mat-select by disabling mat-select from the beginning with [disabled], this way I can detect double click on mat-select without showing mat-options, but when I try to enable mat-select again from my singleClick() function and display the mat-options popup again. I can't because angular doesn't render the new changes until I do a single click again on the component.

Ideally I would like to do a single click on my mat-select, call my singleClick() function and from there enable my mat-select again with [disabled]="false" and finally render the component all at once, but angular detects only the change and it doesn't render the component only at the next click interaction.

What I would like to do is to display the mat-options by calling from my singleClick() function instead. Is there some way to call mat-options programatically from my singleClick function?. I hope you can suggest me some ideas for this or maybe a better way for handling double click event in this situation. [Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8mu2y-ge5b5c?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

This is my component:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Double click posible, single click not showing options until second time clicked" [disabled]="disableMatSelect"
    (click)="singleClick($event)" (dblclick)="doubleClick()" (openedChange)="openedChange($event)" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{ option.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

An here is the function where I want to call mat-options popup:

```
singleClick(event) {
    this.isSingleClick = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.isSingleClick && event.type == 'click') {
        this.disableMatSelect = false;

        //Here I would like to call for mat-options popup

        this.clickEvent = 'Single Click';
        
      }
    }, 250);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had first tried to `preventDefault()`, but this didn't worked. so I come up with this workaround, not the best but it may point you to the right direction.

1. I've created an invisible overlay to listen to the click, then I `stopPropagation()` so the click would never go till the mat-select.
2. I listen to the click, if, inside the `setTimeout()` we didn't had the second click, then open the mat with the `.open()` method, this one could be found by "viewing the child" with `@ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect: MatSelect;` and then `this.matSelect.open()`
3. If we got a second click, then go to the `doubleClick()` method.

There your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k8mu2y-3xtq2v?file=app/select-overview-example.ts), you'll find the answers and the change I had to do.

You could refine the overlay to better fit the size of the mat-select.

### Result

```html
{{clickEvent}}

<div class="select-container">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select #matSelect placeholder=" Normal behavior on single click" (openedChange)=" openedChange($event)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
                {{ option.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="click_listener-container" (click)="singleClick($event);">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
enum values {
  OPTION_1,
  OPTION_2,
  OPTION_3
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css']
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect: MatSelect;

  options = [
    { value: values.OPTION_1, viewValue: 'Option 1' },
    { value: values.OPTION_2, viewValue: 'Option 2' },
    { value: values.OPTION_3, viewValue: 'Option 3' }
  ];

  disableMatSelect = true;
  isSingleClick = false;
  clickEvent = 'Not Clicked';

  constructor() {}

  async singleClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (this.isSingleClick) {
      this.doubleClick();
    } else {
      this.isSingleClick = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.isSingleClick && event.type == 'click') {
          console.log('single click');
          this.clickEvent = 'Single Click';

          this.isSingleClick = false;
          this.matSelect.open();
        }
      }, 250);
    }
  }

  doubleClick() {
    this.isSingleClick = false;
    this.clickEvent = 'Double Click';
    console.log('======>Doble click');
  }

  openedChange(opened: boolean) {
    if (opened === false) {
      this.disableMatSelect = true;
      console.log('disableMatSelect==', this.disableMatSelect);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Edit

In case you have multiple mat select, you may use `@ViewChildren` as follow

```js
@ViewChildren('matSelect')
  matSelections: QueryList<MatSelect>
```

Then, you can loop through the element like follow.

```js
this.matSelections.toArray().map(async (matSelect) => {
  console.log(matSelect)
}),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was really helpful. Regarding this approach is it possible to get the reference to different instances dinamically using ViewChild or something similar to get  different instances of mat-select within the DOM?. I tryed to implement this on a list with mat-accortion but when I try to call or update one element from the list I always get a reference to the first mat-select element only. Here is some of my code: [Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6n1yp-o5vho5?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

Comment: @mrclk yes you can, I did update my answer. but it's kind of not responding to the main question any more  ;)